# Magento 2 Slow Admin Login and Saving Products

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, slowbackend, magento2.1.11

I am using Magento 2 Enterprise version **2.1.11** hosted on **AWS EC2**... 2 server which uses load balancer. I am having slow login query with Admin Login and saving products to database. Everything else works normal.

Checked everything like **PHP** configurations, Magento settings, **Redis** Cache, **CPU** Load and its **Memory** usage. Everything looks good to me.

Around 350 products, 150 attributes, 3 website/store and fresh project in M2.

not sure how to debug this issue.

Comment: You are on enterprise, have you asked this to Magento support team?

Comment: Nope because I dont know that its Magento or Server or 3rd party issue.

Comment: have you enabled mysql slow query log in Magento? it logs all queries that are really slow and that may tell what's the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue after upgrade from **2.1.10** to **2.1.11**.
The only thing that I've found now is a very slow Redis lib, it takes up to 99% of whole "**Admin Login**" action time. Make a note - not Redis service, but Redis php lib.
**Code ref**: `Cm\RedisSession\Handler::read`

Not sure about products saving, but I think it could be the same.
Hope this info will be helpful.

In case I'll find the solution - I post it here.

***UPDATE***: I've found the solution and the reason of the problem.

**Problem reason:**
It is Magento 2.1.11 bug (not present in 2.1.10) caused by the double calling of `\Cm\RedisSession\Handler::read` method that initiates locking on the first call - so, the second call should wait till "**break_after**" config time to get needed data from Redis.

- The first call is happened in:

  > vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php:476
- The second call is happened in:

  > vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php:483

"**break_after**" config timings:

- For BackOffice it is: 30seconds
- For Frontend it is: 5seconds

(you can clearly see these timings in NewRelic traces)

**Solution**: Fix present in "2.2-develop" branch and stable version 2.2.2: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/aaa60b1b72bdc189b38492bd50b0ffb23101173e#diff-b4aa30666c05e391240357a7a435a7a8

Comment: How did you fix it?

Comment: Not fixed yet, working on it. However have already found couple articles that should help:
https://astrio.net/blog/redis-slow-session-magento/ (it is for Magento1 but problem looks similar)
 and https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_RedisSession/issues/16

Comment: I had set disable_locking to 1 in app/etc/env.php file.. and it’s work like charm.. but still we didn’t know the consequences of that change.

Comment: Setting of disable_locking to 1 could cause issues with session usage - in case couple user will login in the same time, login issues could be found.
So I suggest to not use this solution.

Comment: Found the solution - updated comment.

Comment: Thanks man.. Its very helpful for me and others. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: It seems like fix is for 2.2.1. Will it work in 2.1.11 ?

Comment: Yes it will. Current fix does not contain any version related architecture cahnges or something.
I've already tested it and it works well.

Comment: It seems, they reverted back to 2.0 version with some changes. https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Session/SessionManager.php#L501 https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Session/SessionManager.php#L524 https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Session/SessionManager.php#L525

Comment: Just wondering, if this is the main reason backend being slower than frontend. My frontend is still slower than business standard (6-9 sec), but backend is even slower. Any suggestion guys?

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide more details like this is an ongoing issue or you started seeing it recently?
It is a fresh build or migration from M1 to M2?
How big is the catalog (products, categories)?
How many attributes a product has?

Comment: Around 350 products, 150 attributes, 3 website and Fresh project in M2. What else you need ??

Comment: Not sure if you already tried. Change the mode of index to 'Update By Schedule' and try saving the SKU to find out if indexing is the issue.

Any customization around Product or integration to submit product data to 3rd party services? Any error in console during product save? Slow query log can be an option too..

Answer (score -3):

Have you checked the log files? 
How many 3rd party extension you are using?
Are you using catalog flat tables?

One more thing just check about the crons as well...